# how to return the right date using date picker react

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

when i select date 06/11/2022
Datepicker shows 06/11/2022
Console.log shows  `Sun Nov 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)`

I want to get just Date  remouving time by using
`date.toISOString().split('T')[0] ==> 05/11/2022`

what can i do to get the right date?
Thnaks

Comment: My datePicker   ```   <DatePicker className='datePickerDiv' 
                        selected={endDates}
                        onChange={(date) => setEndDates(date)}
                        onSelectedDateEnd={  onSelectedDateEnd(endDates)}
                        dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                    />```

Comment: as @mimia indicated, you should be able to just set the format as a parameter on the object